# Raspberry Pi, Dealing with Crontab

Tags: linux, unix, raspberry-pi, cron

I'm not familiar with Linux and it's my first time using a Raspberry Pi. I am trying to set it to play an Mp3 file every day and came across using Crontab as a viable option. However I'm not sure how to save the files in the correct location because every time I write a script using crontab I can't seem to save it to a viable location...even writing a new crontab to the desktop won't work. Is there a more viable folder for putting all my crontabs? Again I'm new to the system so anything would help,

Thank you for taking the time to read this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply type

```
crontab -e
```

in the command line and add the file you want to run in one of the lines. Here's a short overview on how to write a cronjob:

*Your cron:*

```
 30 20 * * 1-5 omxplayer /home/pi/desktop/wakeupsong.mp3
```

**How to setup a cronjob in general:**

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

---

**Special Characters in cron:**

**Asterisk (*)**

The asterisk indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field. E.g., using an asterisk in the 4th field (month) indicates every month.

**Slash ( / )**

Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

**Comma ( , )**

Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

**Hyphen ( - )**

Hyphens define ranges. For example, 2000-2010 indicates every year between 2000 and 2010 AD, inclusive.

**Percent ( % )**

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % are sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: I want to run this code...

22 30 * * 1-5 /home/pi/desktop/wakeupsong.mp3

But when I try to use the Write Out function to Save it to a file it has the temp section but I don't know where to save it to make it permanent.

Comment: Put the code in a file and run the file via cron @danteMingione

Comment: Sorry had to edit it, hit enter instead of enter+shift

My apologies.

Comment: I don't think you can run a mp3 without another programm. do you have omxplayer installed? You have to add a command, else it won't play...

Comment: I have not. I'll look into downloading it first. Thank you for that tip. How would I run the omxplayer through crontab?

Comment: Actually omxplayer is installed I just ran sudo apt-get install omxplayer and it said it's already the newest version

Comment: One last thing, I'm coding all this outside the GUI do I need to be inside in GUI for it to implement? Also does it matter where the crontab is saved?

Comment: just use crontab -e, then it will be saved in the correct directory for sure. you don't need the gui for it, no

Comment: Doesn't work. I set it to go on at 10:45 and it never came up...hmmm.

Comment: what line have you used?

Comment: 45 22 * * 1-5 omxplayer /home/pi/desktop/wakeupsong.mp3

Comment: try to run it in command line without cron first, and try it without the leading / before home please, you might need to give cron permission to this folder

Comment: If I need to give cron permission to this folder how do I do that? I'll try the other suggestions thanks.

Comment: you can just give 775 permissions to the file by typing chmod 775 /home/pi/desktop/wakeupsong.mp3

Comment: Wow. Just had to reconfigure the timezone...sorry to waste your time I learned a lot.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome! Timezone... Interesting. :-)